# python's function-attributes: getting a list/dict of all assigned attributes

Tags: python

Out of pure curiosity: Is there an easy way (not more then two lines of code) to access the dictionary/list of assigned attributes of a function (from within that function)?

e.g.:

```
def func(*args):
    print("# of arguments = {0} ".format(len(args)))       # normal arguments
    print("# of attributes = {0}".format(len(func_attrs))) # function-attributes

func()

func.func_attr_1 = 'How do i get all attributes from within the associated function?'
func.func_attr_2 = 'How do i get all attributes from within the associated function?'
```

Since functions are callable objects it's possible to provide them with attributes, but
there doesn't seem to bee a way to access a list of these attributes in an easy way.

`locals()` and `globals()` weren't helpful.
`dir()` seems to do the trick, BUT you have to filter your attributes. Thats's somewhat inconvenient if you don't know the attribute-name in advance.

If i can assign an attribute there must .. should be a way to access their directory from within.

**UPDATE**:

i totaly forgot to actually call/invoke = instantiate the function before trying to access the attributes. ... my bad! - sry and thx for the answers ;-)

naturally i tried `func.__dict__` and `dir(func)`, but just didn't instantiate the function-object before doing so ... and in my original test i initially defined a attribute from within the function, then didn't call the function, but tried to access the function-attribute from the outer-scope - which naturally failed!

Comment: I think it's worth asking why you need this.  99 times out of 100, Functions which keep external state (via attributes) shouldn't be functions at all.  At that point, you should probably be using a class ...

Comment: as i stated right at the beginning: out of pure curiosity!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `func.__dict__`, I think it looks nicer to use [vars()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars):

```
>>> def func():
...     pass
... 
>>> func.a = 19
>>> 
>>> func.__dict__
{'a': 19}
>>> vars(func)
{'a': 19}
>>> vars(func) is func.__dict__
True
```

Fewer underscores.

Comment: i like the fewer underscores a lot! ;-)

Answer (score 5):

you means something like this, using `__dict__`:

```
In [11]: def foo():
   ....:     foo=1

In [12]: foo.bar=3

In [13]: foo.__dict__
Out[13]: {'bar': 3}
```

Answer (score 4):

Given the function name `func`, `func.__dict__` is the function's dictionary, which contains all the attributes assigned directly on the function. You can then do membership testing (`if foo in func.__dict__`), iterate over the keys of the dictionary using `for`, or use other methods of dictionaries.